# Trivial power of line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, intuition

I'm trying to understand the following:
[image]

Thinking of a line bundle as a bunch of locally generating sections together with transition functions (which in this case are just multiplication by local sections of the structure sheaf) I wonder what it means that some power of a line bundle is trivial. I guess an example with $N>1$ would answer my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example.** If $(E,O)$ is an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $K$, then we know that the natural map
\begin{align*}
E(K) &\to \operatorname{Pic}^0(E) \\
P &\mapsto \mathcal O_E(P - O)
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism of groups. Thus, if $P$ is a torsion point of $E$ (they always exist: for example over $\mathbb C$ the group $E(\mathbb C)$ is a complex torus $\mathbb C/\Lambda$, for $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb C$ a lattice, so halves of lattice points give $2$-torsion elements), then $\mathcal O_E(P - O)$ is an $n$-torsion line bundle.

**Remark.** If $A$ is an abelian variety over $K = \bar {\mathbb F}_p$, then every point of $A$ is torsion. This follows because any point $P \in A(K)$ is defined over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, and the group $A(\mathbb F_q)$ is finite.

In particular, applying this to $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$ for any smooth projective variety $X$ shows that every line bundle rationally equivalent to $\mathcal O_X$ on a smooth projective variety over (the algebraic closure of) a finite field is torsion. Presumably the citation you gave uses a variant of this statement, for varieties over $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$.

**Remark 1** (thanks to Alex Youcis). I of course have to assume something like $\mathscr L$ is rationally equivalent to $\mathcal O_X$, because otherwise the result I claim is clearly false: think for example about $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$.

**Remark 2.** Because Alex Youcis asked: the precise statement about representability of $\operatorname{Pic}^0_X$ for flat projective $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ with geometrically integral fibres is proven in FGA Explained, Theorem 9.4.8. But this is probably much beyond the type of material the OP is comfortable with.

Short story: it works also over $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, but my proof is fairly elaborate. There might be a much easier argument that I'm unaware of, but this is the standard answer that most algebraic geometers will pull out.

Comment: You should be careful with your last statement. In fact, if $X/k$ is projective (and geometrically integral) and $\text{Pic}(X)$ is torsion then $X$ is a disjoint union of points (and so $\text{Pic}(X)$ is trivial!). The result you claim (which is probably what you meant considering the beginning of your sentence) is that any line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ on $X/\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ that is algebraically equivalent to $\mathcal{O}_X$ is torsion—that is certainly true.

Comment: Also, you don't need that $\text{Pic}^0(X)$ is representable by an abelian scheme, only that it's representable by a finite type scheme—in fact, you really only need that it's a finite-type DM stack. Also, with regard to your last sentence, is it true that over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ things are representable? A sufficiently nice version of $\text{Pic}^0(X)$ exists for projective things over a field if it has a point I believe (you may still have to fppf sheafify). Out of interest, do you know if a similar result hold over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$? Things like this make me nervous! :S

Comment: Thanks for finding the reference!

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as a complement to Remy's nice answer.

The first topological example is the Mobius bundle $L$ on $S^1$ - the transition functions can be taken as multiplcation by $1$ and $-1$. Squaring a line bundle squares the transition maps, so $L^{\otimes 2}$ is trivial. I think it's possible to make an algebraic version of this example by following the lead of example (4) on page 22 of [this book](http://math.uoregon.edu/~ddugger/kgeom.pdf).

There are also algebraic examples in 6.5.1 of Hartshorne: if you take $U = \mathbb P^n \setminus C$ where $C$ is the zero set of a degree $d$ homogeneous polynomial, then the line bundle $L$ on $U$ corresponding to the hyperplane divisor of $C$ will have $L^{\otimes d}$ trivial.

For example, in $\mathbb P^2$ let $C = V(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$ and take the line bundle $L$ on $U$ corresponding to the hyperplane $x=0$, say. Then $L^{\otimes 3}$ will be trivial essentially because of the existence of the globally defined regular function $\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^3+z^3}$, whereas $L^{\otimes 2}$ will be non-trivial (there is no globally defined regular function of the form $\frac{x^2}{p}$).

Also, in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32766/torsion-freeness-of-picard-group) it was noted that for normal projective varieties over $\mathbb C$ there exists a torsion line bundle if and only if $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)$ is non-zero, so they are quite common.

Comment: I just realized that the content of your last paragraph is mostly what I wrote. Sorry for the redundancy!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Nonsense, I really like your point of view. Nice answer!

Comment: Thank you! Those are very helpful examples.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small remark, complementing the two nice answers that already exist.

One can think of torsion in $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ as detecting non-trivial classes in the fundamental group of $X$. More rigorously, I'm thinking of the generalization of standard Kummer theory. Namely, let's suppose (for convenience sake) that $X/k$ is a projective variety and that $m$ is invertible in $k$. Then, one has the following Kummer sequence of (étale) sheaves on $X$:

$$1\to\mu_m\to\mathbf{G}_m\xrightarrow{[m]}\mathbf{G}_m\to 1$$

Passing to the long exact sequence in (étale) cohomology gives one the following short exact sequence

$$1\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)^\times/(\mathcal{O}_X(X)^\times)^m\to H^1_{é \text{t}}(X,\mu_m)\to \text{Pic}(X)[m]\to 1$$

In particular, if we assume, for example, that $k=\overline{k}$, and that $X$ is integral, then

1. $\mu_m=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and so 
   $$H^1_{é\text{t}}(X,\mu_m)=H^1_{é\text{t}}(X,\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})=\text{Hom}_{\text{cont.}}(\pi_1^{é\text{t}}(X),\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$$
2. $\mathcal{O}_X(X)^\times/(\mathcal{O}_X(X)^\times)^m=0$

Thus, we see that we have an isomorphism

$$\text{Hom}_\text{cont.}(\pi_1^{é\text{t}}(X),\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})\cong \text{Pic}(X)[m]$$

which shows precisely in what way torsion line bundles are picking information about the covering theory of $X$.

If one wants to be concrete, the isomorphism described above sends an $m$-torsion line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ to the finite étale cover

$$\mathbf{Spec}(\mathcal{A}(\mathscr{L}))\to X$$

where $\mathcal{A}(\mathscr{L}))$ is the sheaf of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras given by

$$\mathcal{A}(\mathscr{L})=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{m-1}\mathscr{L}^{-i}$$

(I hope I didn't make a mistake in putting dual!) with multiplication which shuffles sections up the chain and then cycles via the choice of an isomorphism

$$i:\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}\xrightarrow{\approx}\mathcal{O}_X$$

This also shows where, really, units modulo their $n^\text{th}$-powers are coming into play since this isomorphism is non-canonical, and so depends on some choice in this quotient group.

Flavor remark: The above is really just a classification of $\mu_m$-torsors as pairs $(\mathscr{L},i)$ of an $m$-torsion line bundle and an isomorphism $i:\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}\xrightarrow{\approx}\mathcal{O}_X$.